# Form inputs don't get validated while typing (@input), only @blur works

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vuelidate

I'm using a combobox with input data validation (Vuelidate):

```html
<template>
    <v-combobox
        clearable
        v-model="surname"
        :items="commonSurnames"
        label="Surname"
        placeholder="Type in the surname"
        class="pt-5 pb-5"
        :error-messages="surnameErrors"
        @input="$v.surname.$touch()"
        @blur="$v.surname.$touch()">
    </v-combobox>
</template>

<script>
import { validationMixin } from 'vuelidate'
import { required, maxLength } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'

export default {
    mixins: [validationMixin],
    validations: {
        surname: {
            required,
            maxLength: maxLength(30),
            validSurname(surname) {
                return (
                    /^[a-zA-Z]-?*.+$/.test(surname)
                )
            }
        },
    name: 'Surnames',

    data() {
        return {
            surname: '',
            [...]
    },
    methods: {
        [...]
    },
    computed: {
        surnameErrors() {
            const errors = []
            if (!this.$v.surname.$dirty) return errors
            !this.$v.surname.validSurname && errors.push('Format must be like: Smith or Smith-Wesson')
            !this.$v.surname.maxLength && errors.push('Surname must be at most 30 characters long.')
            !this.$v.surname.required && errors.push('Surname is required.')
            return errors
    }
}
</script>
```

Versions of components:

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vuelidate": "^0.7.5",
    "vuetify": "^2.2.11"
  },
```

I suppose I did everything as in the [Vuetify Documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/forms/#vuelidate), but my form gets validated a bit differently than what is there, in the docs: I can exceed the limit of 30 characters without being notified about it while typing. I only know it when the input loses focus. The same situation with RegEx validation: any value is accepted without error notification. If the value is not valid, I get notified when leaving the input field.

Did I miss something when copying the example from the docs, or the `@input` listener works incorrectly? Or is it that `v-combobox` can't be validated this way?

Answer (score 0):

`v-combobox` emits `change` or `input` events only when one of its valid values from the dropdown are selected. The text entered in the combobox is actually search input, used to lookup a valid value; and that entry is bound to `v-combobox`'s `search-input` prop.

The [`v-combobox` API](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-combobox/#events) lists `update:search-input` as an event that is fired when the search input changes, so you could use that to bind the validation handler:

```html
<!-- BEFORE: -->
<v-combobox @input="$v.surname.$touch()">

<!-- AFTER: -->
<v-combobox @update:search-input="$v.surname.$touch()">
```

Comment: Hmm, it works a bit different now, i.e. error messages are there from the beginning, but they don't appear again when 1. correct entry is selected (errors disappear then), 2. correct entry gets edited in a way it becomes incorrect. Anyway, thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have a component wrapper around `v-combobox`, `v-autocomplete` and `v-select` (yes, single multi-purpose wrapper). And I would recommend using the code below in a wrapper to avoid copy pasting the fix/workaround.

In general workaround required lookup into Vuetify sources. This led to manipulating `errorBucket` and `valid` in `@update:search-input` listener.

Additionally you might want to emit `'input'`. It requires one small tweak to suppress propagation into `v-combobox` value, since it breaks autocomplete behavior otherwise. Hence `if (this.search) { return; }`

Full example: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/jsek/pen/PomveGB)

```js
Vue.component(
  'my-combobox', {
  template: `
      <v-combobox
         ref="combobox"
         outlined dense
         v-model="selection"
         v-bind="{ ...$attrs, items, rules: validationRules }"
         v-on="$listeners"
         @update:search-input="onSearch"
         @focus="touched = true"></v-combobox>
      `,
  props: {
    value: String,
    items: Array,
    required: Boolean,
    rules: Array,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      selection: null,
      search: null,
      touched: false,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    validationRules() {
      return [
        ...(this.rules || []),
        (v) => !this.required || (v?.length ?? 0) > 0 || 'Value is required',
      ];
    },
  },
  methods: {
    onSearch(v) {
      if (!this.touched) return;
      this.search = v;
      const $self = this.$refs.combobox;
      $self.errorBucket = this.validationRules.filter(f => f(v) !== true);
      $self.valid = $self.errorBucket.length === 0;
      this.$emit('input', v);
    },
  },
  watch: {
    selection: {
      handler(v) {
        this.$emit('input', v);
      },
    },
    value: {
      immediate: true,
      handler(v) {
        if (this.search) { return; }
        this.selection = v;
      },
    },
  },
});
```